# Jfrog system template include multiple templates file

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

I would like to create a jfrog system template and include multiple templates files in it.
I have tried to use "named templates" with "include" but it seems that it is not supported.
And using:

```
{{- template "GitRepo" . }}
```

Only works if I write the template define code inside 'templateDefinition.yml' as below and not in a separate file:

```
{{- define "GitRepo" }}
...
{{- end }}
```

Is there another way to organize the 'define' templates outside of 'templateDefinition.yml'?
Or any other inheritance mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried to use "named templates" with "include" but it seems that it is not supported.

This understanding is correct, Pipelines [supports](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/System+Templates#SystemTemplates-TemplateFunctionsList) `sprig` based templates at the moment. Whereas support for Helm functions are soon to be released which will allow maintaining templates in `_helpers.tpl` file as per Helm standards.

Comment: Thanks, it's great to hear it's coming. I can't wait:)